# WP: Custom fields showing up, but causing errors throughout the site (get_posts)

Tags: php, wordpress

I seem to be having a problem. When I add this bunch of code, the custom fields show up just fine, but everything around the site is in chaos! All of my page titles resort to the same one and the the_content disappears. I'm sure I'm missing something here:

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'project_categories',
            'value' => '"boyle_upcoming"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
    'order' => 'ASC'
));

if($posts) {
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . '<img src="' . get_field('project_header_photo') . '" alt="' . get_the_title($post->ID) . '">' . '<div><em><b>' . get_the_title($post->ID) . '</b><br>' .get_field('project_location') . '<br><br>' . get_field('project_blurb') . '</em></div></a></li>';
    };
}
wp_reset_query();
```

?>

I thought... maybe I had to add the usual loop before and then close it after:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

...but that didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Try changing the `$post` variable in your `foreach` to something else. Wordpress makes use of the global variable `$post`, which is getting overwritten in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Including the code for you. this work and will not mess up your $post.

```
 <?php
         $args = array(
            'post_type'       => 'page',
            'post_status'     => 'publish',
           'posts_per_page'  =>  -1,
           'order'           => 'ASC',
           'meta_query' => array(
                   array(
                       'key' => 'project_categories',
                       'value' => 'boyle_upcoming',
                       'compare' => 'LIKE'
                   )
               ),
         );
         // The Query
         $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

         // The Loop
         if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                $the_query->the_post();
                 echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($the_query->post->ID) . '">' . '<img src="' . get_field('project_header_photo') . '" alt="' . get_the_title($the_query->post->ID) . '">' . '<div><em><b>' . get_the_title($the_query->post->ID) . '</b><br>' .get_field('project_location') . '<br><br>' . get_field('project_blurb') . '</em></div></a></li>';


         } else {
            echo "No DATA";
         }
         /* Restore original Post Data */
         wp_reset_postdata();
         ?>
```